# How to get a specific column value from current row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery, where-clause

How can I get the value of a specific column in the current row? Let's say we have a table "games" with columns "gameid" and "game_type". Each game has multiple winners (one user can win any number of times). Now let's assume we have another table "game_winners" which keeps track of all the game-winners and has "gameid", "userid". What I want to achieve is get the number of unique winners in a particular game. The query I need would look something like this:

```
select gameid, game_type, (
  select count(distinct(userid)) 
  from games 
  join winners 
  where gameid = {gameid of current row}
) as game_winners 
from games 
join winners
```

I'm not sure how to get the gameid from the current row and pass it into the where clause.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a correlated subquery aggregating:

```
SELECT g.gameid,
       g.game_type,
       (SELECT count(DISTINCT w.userid)
               FROM winners w
               WHERE w.gameid = g.gameid) AS game_winners
       FROM games g;
```

Or join and then aggregate:

```
SELECT g.gameid,
       g.game_type,
       count(DISTINCT w.userid) AS game_winners
       FROM games g
            LEFT JOIN winners w
                      ON w.gameid = g.gameid
       GROUP BY g.gameid,
                g.game_type;
```

And BTW, `DISTINCT` is not a function, the parenthesis aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks! The correlated subquery aggregation worked! I was trying to perform join inside the subquery while I could have just performed a simple search using alias names.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !!

Answer (score 0):

This would give you expected result:

```
SELECT
    g.gameid,
    g.game_type,
    count(DISTINCT gw.user_id) as game_winners
FROM
    `game` g
    LEFT JOIN winners gw ON gw.game_id = g.gameid
GROUP BY
    g.gameid;
```

If you want to get result of single game, just add: (replace '1' with your ID)

```
WHERE g.gameid = 1;
```